# Unirest PHP and Mashape API Response

Tags: php, unirest, mashape

i'm test this. Its my first time with unirest and mashape.

Code:

```
<?
require_once 'includes/unirest/Unirest.php';
$cpf = "MY CPF";
$response = Unirest\Request::get("https://consulta-situacao-cpf-cnpj.p.mashape.com/consultaSituacaoCPF?cpf=".$cpf,
  array(
    "X-Mashape-Key" => "MY SECRET KEY"
  )
);

echo $response->raw_body;
?>
```

Result:

```
{"nome":"MY NAME","situacaoCadastral":"CPF STATUS"}
```

But, how i set a especific value ('nome') to a variable?

Like this:

```
MY NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$getResponseVal = $response->raw_body;
$getDecodeData = json_decode($getResponseVal);
$getSpecificValue = $getSpecificValue['nome']; //this will assign nome value  to variable
```

Comment: I try, but result just show the first variable value:

    $getResponseVal = $response->raw_body;
    echo $getResponseVal;
    
    $getDecodeData = json_decode($getResponseVal);
    echo $getDecodeData;
    
    $getSpecificValue = $getSpecificValue['nome'];
    echo $getSpecificValue;

Comment: use print_r() instead of echo because echo cant print array and then what value do you want to show.